# How to put data from table in one div

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I will try to explain better here:

I want to create a div that will hold data from database.

This is how it looks like so far:

```
<div th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
   <div class="wallet" th:text="${wallet.walletName}"></div>
   <div class="wallet" th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"></div>
<br>
</div>
```

And that looks like this:

[image]

But if I set radius, that obviously looks like this:

[image]

So my question is how to make this Thymeleaf to show data in one div?

Even if I want to create a this div clickable I will need to do it for both of them.

Of  course, I tried with something like this:

```
<div th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
    <div class="wallet" th:text="${wallet.walletName}"
         th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}">
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

But I'm getting `Malformed markup: Attribute "th:text" appears more than once in element`

Im not Thymeleaf expert so any advice would be good.

Comment: you have `th:text` twice as attribute of one `div`, what is not valid

Comment: This is for sure not css problem, I need to find out how to save two data from document inside one div or something

Comment: Have you tried: `<div class="wallet"> th:text="${wallet.walletName}"
         th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"
    </div>`

Comment: Doesnt work, same error plus I need to get somehow data from document

Answer (score 0):

You can put `th:text` on any element.  Why not just use a `<span />` instead of a `<div />`?

```
<div class="wallet" th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
   <span th:text="${wallet.walletName}" /><br />
   <span th:text="${wallet.initialBalance}"><br />
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, you can also use [inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) to add the text directly to the `<div />`.

```
<div class="wallet" th:each="wallet : ${wallet}">
   [[${wallet.walletName}]]<br />
   [[${wallet.initialBalance}]]<br>
</div>
```